# auto redirect to mobile site creating issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I am using this to redirect to a mobile version of a webpage (it is not in a sub domain)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "http://www.site.com/mobile/";
}
//-->
</script>

<script language="javascript"> 
<!--
var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
if (mobile) ||  (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) {
  location.replace("http://www.site.com/mobile/");
}
//-->
</script>
```

But when I access from a mobile I get an error that server is not found?

Here is the header of the mobile version

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/icontwo.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/startup.png" />
```

What could be causing this?, If I enter directly it seems to work...

Comment: Your way of commenting the JavaScript is suspect. I doubt it will make a difference, but try this pattern: `<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ javascript-code-here new-line //]]></script>`. (In other words, replace the `<!-- ... //-->` commenting with a CDATA start/end sequence, as recommended [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Properly_Using_CSS_and_JavaScript_in_XHTML_Documents#Using_CDATA_Instead_of_Comments).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be safe I would use `window.location.href` because semantically the `document` object is referring to the DOM document or the HTML elements on the page. Also, some browsers only use `window.location.href`

Also, you seem to be using two redirects:

```
document.location = "http://www.site.com/mobile/";
```

AND

```
location.replace("http://www.site.com/mobile/");
```

which may cause issues. `location.replace` actually destroys the back button capability too which may cause some weird effects not to mention agitated users.

Also, make sure you're not coming onto the site with `https://`